# My Elastic Search query is not giving results, even though the value exsist

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

My Elastic Search Query is

```
GET /My_index_here/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "positions",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "positions.positionID": "04b698d0-afbf-4c09-a21a-d02ec8efaa70"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even though a record with position id mentioned in the query exists but still its now giving the results

This is the sample output i want

```
{
  "took" : 60,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "manpower_cv_index_analyzed_accseparated_new3",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bf03fe1d-4cb0-4e6f-a8a8-3c4b74e9cda3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "primaryKey" : "bf03fe1d-4cb0-4e6f-a8a8-3c4b74e9cda3",
          "addressList" : [
            {
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "fullAddress" : "",
              "location" : {
                "longitudeLatitude" : {
                  "lat" : -2.0,
                  "lon" : -2.0
                }
              },
              "prov" : ""
            }
          ],
          "allSkills" : "",
          "allSoftskills" : "null",
          "awards" : "null",
          "corpusId" : "BODY",
          "custBirthDateRange" : "NoAge",
          "custEMail" : "test@yahoo.com",
          "custFirstName" : "ewe",
          "custLastName" : "rfwe",
          "username" : "testk12@yahoo",
          "genderID" : 0,
          "custMiddleName" : "",
          "custOrigine" : "R",
          "custPBCandID" : "null",
          "custSesso" : "null",
          "custURLcvR" : "",
          "custUpdateDate" : "2023-03-03T08:19:50.2300000",
          "candidateUpdateDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "createdDate" : "2023-02-15T19:24:56.1070000",
          "recruiterActivityRange" : "1W",
          "reconnectionDateRange" : "N/A",
          "cvFile" : "",
          "cvId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "cvLanguage" : "English",
          "cvText" : "",
          "plText" : """
 

     
""",
          "email" : "test@yahoo.com",
          "facebookID" : "",
          "firstname" : "null",
          "fullname" : "ewe rfwe",
          "displayName" : "ewe rfwe",
          "lastname" : "null",
          "linkedInID" : "",
          "references" : "",
          "skypeID" : "",
          "twitterID" : "null",
          "viadeoID" : "null",
          "recruiterComments" : "Recruiter has modified profile details, Recruiter has modified profile details, Recruiter has modified profile details, Recruiter has modified profile details",
          "reconnectionDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "lastTimeIndexed" : "2023-03-03T08:23:23.2328586+00:00",
          "RCandidateId" : "bf03fe1d-4cb0-4e6f-a8a8-3c4b74e9cda3",
          "RAccountId" : [
            "bc73afda-d4f2-42ae-9ec9-32a86e8e445e"
          ],
          "Tags" : [ ],
          "idType" : 0,
          "employeeId" : "",
          "Nationality" : 0,
          "mobilePhone" : "N/A",
          "otherPhone" : "",
          "bestTimeToCall" : "",
          "expectedSalary" : 0,
          "ExpectedSalaryRange" : "<5k",
          "minExpectedSalary" : 0.0,
          "maxExpectedSalary" : 0.0,
          "expectedSalaryPer" : 0,
          "expectedSalaryCurrency" : 21,
          "salaryPerHours" : {
            "gt" : 0.0,
            "gte" : 0.0,
            "lt" : 0.0,
            "lte" : 0.0
          },
          "marketingNotifications" : false,
          "contactByEmail" : false,
          "contactByPhone" : false,
          "contactByText" : false,
          "contractTypeDesc" : "",
          "Classification" : [ ],
          "score" : 0.0,
          "isGeneralPrivacy" : true,
          "generalPrivacyDate" : "2023-02-15T19:24:56.1070000",
          "isLegalNoticePrivacy" : true,
          "legalNoticeSignedDate" : "2023-02-15T19:24:56.1070000",
          "isMarketingPrivacy" : false,
          "marketingPrivacyDate" : "2023-02-15T19:24:56.1070000",
          "isSensitivePrivacy" : false,
          "sensitivePrivacyDate" : "2023-02-15T19:24:56.1070000",
          "lastCandidateActivity" : "2023-02-15T19:24:56.1070000",
          "positionInfoEsLst" : [
            {
              "positionID" : "6c10fa0c-8d9c-49a0-96e7-1c9b2e2b42d6",
              "positionName" : "test1",
              "positionRoleNo" : "",
              "employerID" : "63717ce2-c93a-4686-828e-8499324a99d9",
              "employerName" : "General",
              "sourceName" : "",
              "employeeName" : "",
              "jobStartDate" : "2023-02-15T00:00:00",
              "jobEndDate" : "2023-02-16T00:00:00",
              "candidateFlowStatusTypeID" : 1,
              "candidateFlowStatusID" : "09c75489-5334-4af3-ad80-799393ef3139",
              "lastCandidateFlowStatusDate" : "2023-02-15T00:00:00"
            },
            {
              "positionID" : "04b698d0-afbf-4c09-a21a-d02ec8efaa70",
              "positionName" : "new case",
              "positionRoleNo" : "",
              "employerID" : "63717ce2-c93a-4686-828e-8499324a99d9",
              "employerName" : "General",
              "sourceName" : "Indeed",
              "employeeName" : "",
              "jobStartDate" : "2023-03-01T06:09:12.9430000",
              "jobEndDate" : "2023-03-02T06:09:12.9470000",
              "candidateFlowStatusTypeID" : 3,
              "candidateFlowStatusID" : "c4f2d4b5-17bd-41a0-a171-74b7b15fbb3f",
              "lastCandidateFlowStatusDate" : "2023-03-02T00:00:00"
            }
          ],
          "customFields" : [ ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i have pasted the mappings in the different question
here is the link to the question where mappings is pasted

[My Elastic Search query is not giving results, even though the value exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75633702/my-elastic-search-query-is-not-giving-results-even-though-the-value-exist)

Comment: Can you also share a sample document and the index mapping